# Export sql azure DB as bacpac file without including data for certain tables

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure-sql-database, data-tier-application

When I export a sql azure database as data tier application from sql server management studio I get the option to tick off certain tables but then these tables are not included in the resulting file.

I want to export these tables schemas, but ignore their data (import empty tables essentially). For all the other tables I also want the data.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Clement,where you want to export the data , on-premises or other location .Export with the latest 2016 SSMS for best results.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a perfect copy of a table and the whole schema by doing:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO new_table FROM old_table
```

If you have a linked server or a database on the same server that is called, let's say, `database_copy` you can actually iterate all tables and you will end up having the same number of tables, all with the same schema.

Otherwise, if you can [mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15) the data or encrypt them. But in this case they will still be on the database